# Ubuntu 14.04.5 kernel update doesn't show up new kernel in the boot menu

Tags: 14.04

Below are the install logs generated after executing the command "apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-image-generic-lts-xenial" however while booting up the system I tried to select 4.4 kernel but its not showing up in there. Any idea's ?

```
root@xxxxx:/etc/grub.d# cat /boot/grub/menu.lst|grep 4.4
title           Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-70-generic
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic root=UUID=27a6c527-5e55-472a-af0e-8bde546becda ro quiet splash
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
title           Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-70-generic (recovery mode)
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic root=UUID=27a6c527-5e55-472a-af0e-8bde546becda ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
root@gbssyd03:/etc/grub.d#
```

`apt` log:

```
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic (4.4.0-70.91~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.16.0-77-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
Found kernel: /memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

Setting up linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.70.57) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-70 (4.4.0-70.91~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic (4.4.0-70.91~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.70.57) ...
Setting up linux-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.70.57) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic (4.4.0-59.80~14.04.1) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

=====================

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-59-generic x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information disabled due to load higher than 4.0

New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack
ended on 2016-08-04:
 * http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

The following packages are no longer supported:
 linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-77-generic linux-image-3.16.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic

Please upgrade them to a supported HWE stack or remove them if you
no longer need them.

Comment: You must have tried to do this before, because the prior kernel 4.4.0-59-generic didn't get installed correctly either. So why are you trying to install xenial kernels? Is there a reason why you couldn't follow the normal, supported, upgrade path from 14.04.5 to something newer?

Comment: I have followed the instructions displayed on screen after logging in. 
WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack
ended on 2016-08-04:
 * http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-image-generic-lts-xenial

and reboot your system.

Comment: In fact we did not want to goto 16 at this point , probably need to review the compatibility as we got atlassian suit nginx svn etc running in containers just want to make sure its all compatible before we go to version 16. This is standalone server and if anything goes wrong that's going to add more risk and developers wont be able to do any deployments :( until it comes back up. Hope that make sense.  So any inputs on making kernel 4.4 visible under advanced boot menu list and bootable will be a great help.

Comment: '"
root@xxxx:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
root@xxxx:~# uname -r
3.16.0-59-generic
"'

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic` and then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I have moved the file vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic to a different directory to free up some space in /boot which is from previous upgrade attempt, I should have used purge etc. Is it advisable to move it back and run the command again or just run it as the way you suggested ?

Comment: You'll need to move it back to do either the --configure or a purge.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, I will give it a try .. will keep you posted :)